# Dataset update losing precision

Tags: ms-access, dataset, tableadapter

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 to build a Windows application, using an Access *.mdb for it's memory. Most of the data reads and writes work correctly, except for where I'm entering data into a datagridview, and using a table adapter update to save the data to the memory via a dataset data source. Again, that works fine until I get to 9 significant figures, and I start to loose precision, for example, 1,033,241.78 saves as 1,033,241.75.
Where I use an oledb connection, I get no such precision loss; 1,033,241.78 saves as 1,033,241.78.
The numeric fields of the database are double, the numeric fields of the dataset are double, so according to all of the best search results, I should be no-where near my precision limit.
Please, any clues?

Comment: But by using `Double` you are facing floating point errors. For amounts and quantities in Access, always use data type `Currency` or `Decimal` to avoid these. There are examples where `Double` is preferable, but these are few. One is for currency exchange - se my project [VBA.CurrencyExchange](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.CurrencyExchange).

Comment: Hi, thanks. 
I've tested these. Using currency, the table adapter fails. Decimal didn't work for some reason (I tested it some time ago), but I'll check out again in more detail.